# Python script that uses Zeromq stops receiving messages

Tags: python, configuration, network-programming, zeromq

I have a python script that uses zeromq with pyzmq connector. Script is really a basic one, it uses ZMQ_REP socket to receive a message, do something small with it and send it back, all that in an infinite loop. No multithreading or anything else.

Problem is when I run that service on my server, after about ~15h it stops responding, and it is still running and port is still binded. So when I send a message to that script with ZMQ_REQ socket, I don`t get an answer. When I restart the  script, it gets all that messages that was not used, from zmq queue, so I suspect the problem is in the pyzmq connector or some python or zmq socket configuration.

I tried that script on 2 different servers in 2 different countries, 1 running ArchLinux, second CentOS, and on my local machine, and behaviour is the same. Also I tried to run python script that uses basic python sockets that just receive string message and sends it back and it is working and sending back messages without problems for 10 days now without restarting it. So problem is surely in zmq/pyzmq somewhere.

Comment: Are both the ZMQ_REQ and ZMQ_REP scripts on the same machine, or distributed across a network?  Are you using the basic `socket.send()` and `socket.recv()` functions for communication, or are you using a Poller?  Have you tried logging the ZMQ_REP script to see exactly where it's getting stuck?

Comment: Can you post some code? Does the memory usage increase before the process is killed? What version of zmq and python are you using? I have faced issues with python long running scripts before and a simple solution could be to restart the process after it deals with N requests (thats how gunicorn handles memory leaks in their workers).

Answer (score 1):

How often are messages being sent? You may need to implement heartbeats to maintain a reliable connection. The "[Paranoid Pirate](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3aall#Robust-Reliable-Queuing-Paranoid-Pirate-Pattern)" pattern listed in the guide works pretty well.